# Как передать Context

Tags: java, android

Пишу клавиатуру, пытаюсь вывести информацию из БД

```
public final class InputLogic {

String test, test2;



public final RichInputConnection mConnection;
private final RecapitalizeStatus mRecapitalizeStatus = new RecapitalizeStatus();

public final TreeSet<Long> mCurrentlyPressedHardwareKeys = new TreeSet<>();


public InputLogic(final LatinIME latinIME) {

    mLatinIME = latinIME;
    mConnection = new RichInputConnection(latinIME);


}
```

Пытаюсь передать Context  `public InputLogic(final LatinIME latinIME, Context context)`

Но при этом в другом классе ругается эта строка

```
final InputLogic mInputLogic = new InputLogic(this);
```

Как в таком случае передать контекст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило, `Context` - это `Activity`, которая находится на переднем плане, для сервиса - Service. Это наследники базового абстрактного класса `Context`.

Для того, чтобы получить контекст в стороннем классе вне Активити/Сервиса, его нужно туда передать при создании и, если класс не статический, даже сохранить для дальнейшего использования.

Во фрагменте контекст можно получить через `getActivity()`, в некоторых классах (например, `View`) через `getBaseContext()` или `getApplicationContext()`.

Что касается вашего примера, не очень понятна взаимосвязь этих трёх строк:

```
public InputLogic(final LatinIME latinIME, Context context)
final InputLogic mInputLogic = new InputLogic(this); //кто здесь this?
public InputLogic(final LatinIME latinIME) {}
```

Они все про разное.